# How to implement linked list using OOP?

Tags: python, oop, linked-list

I'm trying to implement a linked list using OOPs and private variables. However, I'm getting **`'str' object has no attribute 'get_data'`** when I call the `display` method of the `LinkedList` class. Also, I feel the `add` method is also not correct.

When I print `self.__head` and `self.__tail` in `add()`, the code never enters the else part and it outputs:

```
Sugar Sugar
Milk Milk
Tea Tea
Biscuit Biscuit
```

Below is my code:

```
class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__head=None
        self.__tail=None

    def get_head(self):
        return self.__head

    def get_tail(self):
        return self.__tail

    def add(self,data): # Skeptical about it

        if self.__tail is None:
            self.__head=Node(data).get_data()
            self.__tail = self.__head
            print(self.__head,self.__tail)
        else:
            b=Node(data)
            self.__tail= b.get_data()
            self.__head = self.__tail
            b.set_next(self.__tail)
            self.__tail = b.get_next()

            print(self.__head,self.__tail)


    def display(self): # Gives the error

        temp = self.__head
        msg = []
        c = Node(temp)
        while (temp is not None):
            print(temp.get_data())

            msg.append(str(temp.get_data()))

            temp = temp.get_next()

        msg = ''.join(msg)
        print(msg)

class Node:
    def __init__(self,data):
        self.__data=data
        self.__next=None

    def get_data(self):
        return self.__data

    def set_data(self,data):
        self.__data=data

    def get_next(self):
        return self.__next

    def set_next(self,next_node):
        self.__next=next_node


list1=LinkedList()
list1.add("Sugar")

#print(list1.get_head())
#print("Element added successfully")

list1.add("Milk")
list1.add("Tea")
list1.add("Biscuits")
list1.display()
```

Comment: Leaving aside the unnecessary double-underscore name-mangling, and the very unpythonic use of getters and setters, I would say there is a lot of weird things going on in this code. What is the point of `self.__head=Node(data).get_data()`??? Why not just the more straightforward and equivalent `self.__head = data`? But that is probably not what you want at all...

Comment: There is no private in python (and your attributes are private either). Remove the getter and setter and just use `self.data` and `self.next`.

Comment: Because data is a private variable of the node class.

Comment: And __ is used to create private variables

Comment: There aren't private things in Python as Daniel mentioned. Even if you use `__` to *try* to make things private I could just take the nuclear option and fix that if I really wanted access.

Comment: I will try that , but what if I actually want to use __

Comment: @HackersInside there are no private variables in Python. But leaving all that aside, why are you doing `self.__head=Node(data).get_data()` Why not just the more straightforward and equivalent `self.__head = data`? I don't think you actually want to do *either*, but think about what is happening there.

Answer (score 1):

This seems suspicious:

```
self.__head = Node(data).get_data()
```

Considering you're not even referencing the node anymore... Then trying to call the methods of the Node object. Even then your implementation is still wrong.

I'm sure there's other issues but you can google this or actually do your own project / homework.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it more concisely by using several singly-linked-list implementation "tricks" I know about.

A linked-list is always composed of at least one *sentinel* node which is automatically created and stored in the instance attribute `self._tail`. Having it has has a couple of benefits.

1. Knowing where the `tail` is make adding something to the end quick and easy.
2. The list is never empty, so that special case needn't be to checked. A nice side-effect of that means that iterating through elements of the list requires only following the `self._next` until it's the sentinel node—a single conditional expression.

The other "trick" is when adding a new last element right *before* the current sentinel node—which sound slow to do in singly-linked-list because it appears to require modifying the `Node` to the one being added. To achieve the effect of doing this, but avoiding actually doing so, what it does is turn the *existing* sentinel node into what a new `Node` would contain, and make's its `_next` attribute be a new sentinel it creates to replace previous one that's be reused.

How that helps understand what's going on in the following code:

```
class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self._tail = Node()
        self._head = self._tail

    def add(self, data):
        """ Add an item to the end of the linked list. """
        new_tail = Node()
        self._tail.set_data(data)  # Convert existing tail into a data node.
        self._tail.set_next(new_tail)
        self._tail = new_tail

        print('adding:', data)

    def display(self):
        """ Traverse linked list and print data associated with each Node. """
        print('\nLinked list contents:')
        curr = self._head
        while curr is not self._tail:
            print('  ' + curr.get_data())
            curr = curr.get_next()


class Node:
    def __init__(self, data=None):
        self._data = data
        self._next = None

    def get_data(self):
        return self._data

    def set_data(self, data):
        self._data = data

    def get_next(self):
        return self._next

    def set_next(self, next_node):
        self._next = next_node


if __name__ == '__main__':
    list1 = LinkedList()

    list1.add("Sugar")
    list1.add("Milk")
    list1.add("Tea")
    list1.add("Biscuits")

    list1.display()
```

Output:

```
adding: Sugar
adding: Milk
adding: Tea
adding: Biscuits

Linked list contents:
  Sugar
  Milk
  Tea
  Biscuits
```

Answer (score -1):

So, I have worked out an answer to my problem. Thank you, everyone, for the help. I'm still not clear about this:

I know python doesn't by default come with private variables when compared to languages like Java, but I believe python is about respecting conventions and '__' is a convention to tell another developer that this particular entity is private.

However, in my case, I wouldn't be able to access the data and next attributes of Node class form LinkedList class and vice versa directly as the name gets resolved to **_Classnmae__attribute_name** when using private variables. So a better solution is to use getters and setters, because common that is what they are for.

```
def add(self,data):
    #Remove pass and write the logic to add an element
    new_node = Node(data)
    if self.__head is None:
        self.__head = self.__tail = new_node
    else:
        self.__tail.set_next(new_node)
        self.__tail = new_node

def display(self):
    #Remove pass and write the logic to display the elements
    temp = self.__head       
    msg = []
    c = Node(temp)
    while (temp is not None):
        msg.append(str(temp.get_data()))
        temp = temp.get_next()
    msg = ' '.join(msg)
    print(msg)
```

> **Algorithm**:
>
> add(data)
>
> 1. Create a new node with the data
> 2. If the linked list is empty (head node is not referring to any other node), 
>      make the head node and the tail node refer to the new node
> 3. Otherwise,
>
>    a. Make the tail node’s link refer to new node
>
>    b. Call the new node as tail node

Comment: "but I believe python is about respecting conventions and '__' is a convention to tell another developer that this particular entity is private." No, the convention is for *single underscores* for "private" variables (non-public parts of the API). Double-underscores is for name-mangling, to prevent collisions in *subclasses*. And you shouldn't use getters and setters in Python, *especially* if all they do is get and set a value. Rather, just use normal attributes, then use a `property` if you ever want to control access. Read [this](https://www.python-course.eu/python3_properties.php)